# Simulating Signed Bit Multiplication in Java

Tags: java, binary

I'm attempting to create a java simulator that will simulate all the possible signed multiplications for 4 bit numbers.

My code layout uses chars to represent the actual bits.

My issue I have now is splitting up my int inputs (multiplicand/multiplier) bit by bit to place each bit into a new char so I can manipulate each char (ie bit) to perform signed multiplication.

Any pointers are greatly appreciated

```
public class SignedMultiplication {

int multiplicand, multiplier, expected_product, actual_product;
char md_bit0, md_bit1, md_bit2, md_bit3, mr_bit0, mr_bit1, mr_bit2, mr_bit3;
char pr_bit0, pr_bit1, pr_bit2, pr_bit3, pr_bit4, pr_bit5, pr_bit6, pr_bit7;

for(multiplicand=-8;multiplicand<8;++multiplicand){

// set multiplicand bits for two's complement 
md_bit0 = ;
md_bit1 = ;
md_bit2 = ;
md_bit3 = ;

    for(multiplier = -8; multiplier < 8; ++multiplier){

    // set multiplier bits for two's complement 
    mr_bit0 = ;
    mr_bit1 = ;
    mr_bit2 = ;
    mr_bit3 = ;

    // perform 4 bit multiplier operation
    // result is in pr_bit0 through pr_bit7

    // set actual product to value converting 2's complement to an integer
    actual_product = ;

    expected_product = multiplicand * multiplier;

        if( expected_product != actual_product ){
            System.out.println("Multiplicand: " + multiplicand + " Multiplier: " + multiplier + 
                    " Expected Result: " + expected_product + " Obtained: " + actual_product );
        }
    }
}
```

}